# Why would the filter combo box not appear on the spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Just what the title states; the sheet in the work-book is not protected. It is possible to select a column, and then click upon the 'filter'. The expected result on performing this action is to see a combo in the first row listing all entries in each row of that sheet.

This fails silently; there is no warning/error, and yet the filter combo-box fails to appear on the first row for any column in this sheet.

Why would the filter combo-box fail to appear ?

EDIT: Follow-up detail that I failed to spot earlier. The first row simply is not visible; row count that appears to the left of the spread-sheet begins at '2' instead of '1'. I take this to mean the filter comboy probably remains invisible because that entire row is hidden. How do I make the first row visible?

Comment: What version? Are there any spaces between the headers and the data?

Comment: 2007. No spaces. It's a biggie though, 16MB almost

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is an answer, but not sure how else to test it.

Is it possible that someone has included a macro that is hiding autofilter indicators?
Turn off the filter and run this

```
Sub ShowDropdowns()
 Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, VisibleDropdown:=True
End Sub
```

If you still see nothing, then I don't know.

I at one time had a huge sheet that would never turn them off, which was the opposite problem, and it was related to corruption in the sheet and how it was constructed.